# How to Remove tty login?

Tags: 18.04, tty

when I turn on my ubuntu 18.04 it goes to tty login every time.
I tried

```
systemctl set default multi-user.target
systemctl start gdm
```

and this helped me to quit tty login and go to desktop environment
but I want to get rid of using these sort of command and directly go to desktop environment on booting system again

As I am new to linux so please provide simple answer. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` and open up terminal. Use command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` to switch to Gnome display manager. When the  `Reconfigure window` appears, you do the following: 1. Use `up` or `down` arrows to position the cursor on `gdb3` display manager. 2. Hit `spacebar` to mark your selection (please don’t ignore this step). 3. Use `tab` to navigate to `OK` button and press `return`. After this you you will go to gnome desktop. You reboot and verify that you go directly to Gnome desktop login instead TTY login. Good Luck!

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` and open up terminal. @Gagan Puri, you issue this command to check out your current display manager:`cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` and please post the output.